# Draw SVG on canvas at specific height - IE11 not working

Tags: javascript, svg

I know why this doesn't work, I just don't know how to fix it.
I have this codepen which shows the issue. In all browsers it works, except IE11:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/QjmmGm

If you open up the console, you will see in any browser except IE11 it will show the width and height.
In IE11 it shows them both as 0.
That is from this bit of code:

```
// Bind to the image onload function
img.onload = function () {

  console.log(img.width);
  console.log(img.height);

  // Draw our image
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // Release our URL
  domUrl.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Basically, IE does not get the width and height of an SVG....
I made a fork of the above to show that I can get it to draw the SVG but it scales itself.

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/yYKKGr

This works, but I need to resize to an actual height (which is worked out by the original size of the SVG) so I need access to the width / height properties of the SVG.
Does anyone know how I can access them on IE11?